# I want to set the FN key on my laptop to toggle

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, keyboard-shortcuts, regedit, fn-key

What I want to do, is to set the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key as a toggle (*same as caps lock*).

I was thinking this should be possible through registry, but I do not have enough knowledge of it to fix this.
(Could also be inverted, so that when I hold it down I can use the <kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F12</kbd> keys).

Comment: What model laptop do you have? You may have something like a `fn lock` key that will allow you to change the way the key behaves.

Comment: My laptop is not a particular make and model, it's sold without a brand. The model number is W840SU.

Comment: @EvenSøsveen in my experience most such are Clevo machines. I'm a big fan; the build quality is usually excellent. In any case, their keyboards don't usually have a Fn-lock key or combo.

Comment: They do not appear to have this function, no. But yes, the build quality is good, and it has everything I was looking for in a laptop, for a much lower price than the competition!
Will never buy anything else again, unless it's a very good offer somewhere.
It's also good to buy these, because they come "clean" - without windows. And since I've mostly been using Linux, I don't see why I should buy a Windows machine if I don't have to.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite possibly not possible, I'm afraid.  Usually the Fn key isn't something that's passed to the operating system, but rather implemented in the keyboard's firmware.

Take my laptop, for example.  Fn+F3 is mute.  If I (on Debian, but the same principles apply to Windows) run `showkey --scancodes`, to see what my keyboard is doing, I get no output if I press and release Fn.  If I press and release F3, I get `^[OR0x3d 0xbd`, and if I do Fn+F3 I get the entirely distinct scancode sequence `0xe0 0x20 0xe0 0xa0`.  Compare this to the situation with ctl: press-and-release gets:

```
0x9c 
0x1d 
0x9d
```

And ctl+f3 gets:

```
0x1d 
^[[1;5R0x3d 
0xbd 0x9d
```

As you can see, Fn isn't passed to the OS; it *directly changes* what the OS can see.

So **short of changing the keyboard's firmware chip**, and **unless it already has a Fn-lock key** as Michael Frank commented, **turning Fn into a toggle is not going to be possible**.

The *inversion* option, however, is doable.  There may be an option for it in the BIOS, but if not, you'll need to find out what windows thinks the scancodes of both the F1-F12 keys and the result of Fn+[those] are.  For each key, you'd swap the result of its fn+key scancode with its unmodified one.  This is something that can be done on Windows with regedit, though there are probably easier tools, and on Linux with the appropriate tools, probably a text editor and setxkbmap.  Unfortunately, I can't help you with that.

Comment: This is an amazing reply, thank you so much for this. Very interesting to see how much some people know. I've spent some more time online looking for an answer, and taking your reply into consideration - this is not possible.